# Laravel email verification in other model

Tags: php, laravel

I need do email verification for comments system. When guest create comment,  he can write email, name, and body of comment. When user send comment, I need verify email him. And If he confirms email, then I need to publish comment. How can I do it with standard Laravel Email Verification? I have model `Comment`, and I have in tables comments columns: `email`, `email_verified_at`. Maybe I can implement Trait Email Verification for model `Comment`? I don't need to check whether user has verified his email address or not. If yes, then user should be able to post a comment. I need every comment verify email him. 1 comment = 1 verified email (even if it is repeated), how I can do it?

In model comment I tryied implement VerifyEmail:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class Comment extends Model implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ...
}
```

But what I need do next? In docs only one middleware: `->middleware('verified')` and this for user model, how I can send notification email activation for comment model and do middleware for comment model?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make a custom verification. You can add a ***email_verified*** boolean column and set it false by default. 
Make a route and method which will change the comment's ***email_verified*** value to true from false.
In comments displaying page, you only show the comments which's ***email_verified*** column is true.
Now whenever a user make a comment, sent him a email containing the URL for that comment which will change the ***email_verified*** to true for that comment.

It's basic process and you can make it more efficient using *separate table*, *token* and *laravel Observer*.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the email verification for another model.

Create an observer for the comment model then add a verified boolean to the migration table of the comment.

When the comment is created your observer will be able to trigger a notification to the guest.

Comment: Could you explain how to trigger the boolean to be set to true from the email? Is there token generation function or something like that out of the box?

Comment: You could use a token verification, I probably would not go that far and just turn the created at time into an epoch and use that combined with the id of the comment. e.g. id:timestamp into base64 and decode and split on verification.

Comment: Also sorry I did not answer your question, I don't believe there is a default token generation if you wanted to go that way you would have to create another field in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have found an example code for those who would need it: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-email-verification-on-other-model